# Is there AndAlso equivalent for Matlab?

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, breakpoints

I need to check validity of an expression and if it was true then check 2nd exp.
It can be written in 2 if-end structures but I want to put condition in conditional breakpoint, and I think it is not possible to write 2 if in one line.
But AndAlso can solve my problem.
any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the shortcut `AND`, i.e. `&&`, the second statement is only evaluated if the first one was true. Thus, something like

```
i>1 && foo(i)==3
```

should do the trick.

Comment: yes. Also worth mentioning that a list of conditions can be checked with `all(X)`.

Comment: @SanjayManohar But if I write all(X), wouldn't matlab first evaluate X, and thus wouldn't all([i>1,foo(i)]) evaluate foo(i) whatever i?